# Can I use a CSV file like a (MSsql or mysql or BDE database) in C++ Builder?

Tags: csv, c++builder

I apologise in advance if this question isn't very specific.

Would it be possible to do the following.

**when the application loads**

read the contents of a CSV file into a dataset.

**while the application is running**

operate on that dataset exactly as if it were a mysql or mssql or bde database (run queries.  insert records.  delete records.  alter records.)

**when the application closes** - write the dataset back to the csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load the file into a TClientDataset, operate on the dataset and apply the changes back to a file.

Comment: OK I've done that.  I have the following code in a tbutton...

ClientDataSet1->FileName = "c:\\testdata.csv";
ClientDataSet1->Open();

 AddFiles(Edit1->Text);
 ClientDataSet1->SaveToFile("c:\\testdata.csv");

I get an error saying "missing data provider or data packet"  I was hoping that...

Comment: ... dealing directly with a file wouldn't require a data providor.

Comment: It doesn't. Have a look at http://www.youcantwin.com/dasblogce/2007/11/11/TClientDatasetSaveToCsv.aspx for some example code